# any tools to analyze wmv file format?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-media-player, wmv

I am developing some application (similar to media player but performing more domain specific things) based on wmv file. I am wondering any existing free tools to analyze wmv format -- I am interested about general information about a specific wmv file (like frame rate, size, and do not need too defailed information). I need especially information like whether the wmv file is corrupted, and how wmv file is corrupted (e.g. index corruption). I need such tool to verify my application can report the same error. Any recommended tools?

I am developing with C# + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + Windows. But any tools based on Windows are appreciated.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually, [mplayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) is (open source, free) and does (will analyze and decode) all of those things.

And, it even plays the movie ... go figure

Comment: I used mplayer before, and I think it could only play video. Could it analyze format, i.e. if a video cannot be played, what part (e.g. index part of wmv file) is wrong?

Comment: If yes, can you show me how (any docs)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://ffmpeg.org/. Its sources can be compiled for Windows

Comment: Thanks! I find it is a good codec. But does it contain analyze function (e.g. analyze what is wrong with a currupted video, like saying index part of wmv file is wrong)? I did not find such function, appreciate if you could let me know how to use ffmpeg to do such analysis functions?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media ASF Viewer 9 Series will give you a lot of details on the ASF (WMV) structure
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/format/ASFViewer.aspx